# ¿Cómo seleccionar múltiples archivos en un Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT?

Tags: android

Actualmente tengo el siguiente código, pero solamente me permite seleccionar un archivo, sin embargo he visto que otras aplicaciones usan el mismo **file chooser** y permiten seleccionar varios archivos.

```
private void showFileChooser(String type) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

    intent.setType(type);
    try {
        startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a File to Upload"),
                FILE_SELECT_CODE);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        // Potentially direct the user to the Market with a Dialog
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please install a File Manager.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Me parece que el titulo debe ser : "ACTION_GET_CONTENT"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Seleccionar múltiples imágenes de galería.

Para seleccionar múltiples archivos, debes definir [EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE).

> **[EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE)** Extra utilizado para indicar que un intento
> puede permitir al usuario seleccionar y devolver múltiples elementos.
> Este es un extra booleano; **El valor predeterminado es falso. Si es
> verdadero, una implementación puede presentar al usuario una UI en la
> que puede elegir varios elementos que se devuelven al llamante.** Cuando
> esto sucede, deben devolverse como la parte getClipData() de la
> Intención del resultado.

importante comentar que esto funciona desde Android 4.4 (KitKat) por lo tanto es recomendable agregar una validación si tu aplicación funciona para API´s menores.

```
//    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a File to Upload"), FILE_SELECT_CODE);
        }catch(Exception e){
               Toast.makeText(this, "Please install a File Manager.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
//    }
```